# How do I correctly pass parameters to my login implementation with clean architecture and bloc?

Tags: flutter, dart, clean-architecture, flutter-bloc, dio

I am currently learning Flutter with clean architecture. I am trying to pass 3 parameters, company, username and pin to my login implementation as my API requires these 3 parameters. I am using flutter bloc and dio. Currently the implementation works with the constant variables I have defined in my const.dart file. I want to pass the TextFormField values as parameters to my API request on button press while also making the request keeping to the clean architecture principal.

**Login Button**

```
  _buildLoginButton(context) {
    return OutlinedButton(
      onPressed: () {
        // Dispatch the GetLoginDetails event with the login details
        if (formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
          BlocProvider.of<RemoteLoginDetailsBloc>(context).add(
            GetLoginDetails(
              companyController.text.trim(),
              usernameController.text.trim(),
              pinController.text.trim(),
            ),
          );
        }
      },
      child: const Text("Login"),
    );
  }
```

**RemoteLoginBloc**

```
class RemoteLoginDetailsBloc
    extends Bloc<RemoteLoginDetailsEvent, RemoteLoginState> {
  final GetLoginDetailsUseCase _getLoginUseCase;

  RemoteLoginDetailsBloc(this._getLoginUseCase)
      : super(const RemoteLoginDetailsLoading()) {
    on<GetLoginDetails>(onGetLoginDetails);
  }

  void onGetLoginDetails(
      GetLoginDetails event, Emitter<RemoteLoginState> emit) async {
    final dataState = await _getLoginUseCase();

    if (dataState is DataSuccess && dataState.data!.isNotEmpty) {
      emit(RemoteLoginDone(dataState.data!));
    }

    if (dataState is DataFailed) {
      debugPrint(
          'Data Failed Error: ${dataState.error!.message} $loginAPIBaseURL');
      emit(RemoteLoginError(dataState.error!));
    }
  }
}
```

**RemoteLoginState**

```
abstract class RemoteLoginState extends Equatable {
  final List<LoginEntity>? loginDetails;
  final DioException? error;

  const RemoteLoginState({this.loginDetails, this.error});

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [loginDetails!, error!];
}

class RemoteLoginDetailsLoading extends RemoteLoginState {
  const RemoteLoginDetailsLoading();
}

class RemoteLoginDone extends RemoteLoginState {
  const RemoteLoginDone(List<LoginEntity> login) : super(loginDetails: login);
}

class RemoteLoginError extends RemoteLoginState {
  const RemoteLoginError(DioException error) : super(error: error);
}
```

**RemoteLoginEvent**

```
abstract class RemoteLoginDetailsEvent {
  const RemoteLoginDetailsEvent();
}

class GetLoginDetails extends RemoteLoginDetailsEvent {
  GetLoginDetails();
}
```

**GetLoginDetailsUsecase**

```
class GetLoginDetailsUseCase
    implements UseCase<DataState<List<LoginEntity>>, void> {
  final LoginRepository _loginRepository;

  GetLoginDetailsUseCase(this._loginRepository);

  @override
  Future<DataState<List<LoginEntity>>> call({void params}) {
    return _loginRepository.getLogonDetails();
  }
}
```

**LoginRepository**

```
abstract class LoginRepository {
  // API Methods
  Future<DataState<List<LoginEntity>>> getLogonDetails();
}
```

**LoginRepositoryImpl**

```
class LoginRepositoryImpl implements LoginRepository {
  //final LoginDatabase _loginDatabase;
  final LoginApiService _loginApiService;
  LoginRepositoryImpl(this._loginApiService);

  @override
  Future<DataState<List<LoginModel>>> getLogonDetails() async {
    try {
      final httpResponse = await _loginApiService.getLogonDetails(
        apiKey: telMeApiKey,
        lcomp: lcomp,
        luser: luser,
        lpin: lpin,
      );

      // Log the request and response for debugging
      debugPrint('Request: ${httpResponse.response.requestOptions.uri}');
      debugPrint('Response status code: ${httpResponse.response.statusCode}');

      if (httpResponse.response.statusCode == HttpStatus.ok) {
        return DataSuccess(httpResponse.data);
      } else {
        return DataFailed(DioException(
          error: httpResponse.response.statusMessage,
          response: httpResponse.response,
          type: DioExceptionType.badResponse,
          requestOptions: httpResponse.response.requestOptions,
        ));
      }
    } on DioException catch (e) {
      debugPrint('TelMeLogonRequest - Error:$e');
      return DataFailed(e);
    }
  }
}
```

Currently this passes constant variables which are hardcoded but I want to pass dynamic values based on the users input in 3 TextFormFields to the lcomp, luser and lpin parameters inside the LoginRepositoryImpl file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, you should pass your parameters through all methods until the point of execution.

As you pass string parameters to event:

```
GetLoginDetails(
              companyController.text.trim(),
              usernameController.text.trim(),
              pinController.text.trim(),
            ),
```

but you don't have this parameters in event:

```
class GetLoginDetails extends RemoteLoginDetailsEvent {
  GetLoginDetails();
}
```

but you should:

```
class GetLoginDetails extends RemoteLoginDetailsEvent {
  const GetLoginDetails(this.company, this.userName, this.pin);
  
  final String company;
  final String userName;
  final String pin;
}
```

then you could use this in bloc to pas it to your usacase:

```
class RemoteLoginDetailsBloc
    extends Bloc<RemoteLoginDetailsEvent, RemoteLoginState> {
  final GetLoginDetailsUseCase _getLoginUseCase;

  RemoteLoginDetailsBloc(this._getLoginUseCase)
      : super(const RemoteLoginDetailsLoading()) {
    on<GetLoginDetails>(onGetLoginDetails);
  }

  void onGetLoginDetails(
      GetLoginDetails event, Emitter<RemoteLoginState> emit,
  ) async {
    final dataState = await _getLoginUseCase.call(
                                       event.company,
                                       event.userName,
                                       event.pin,
                       );
    ...
```

and now you can pas this params in method of your repo:

```
...
      @override
      Future<DataState<List<LoginEntity>>> call(
             String company, String userName, String pin,
      ) => _loginRepository.getLogonDetails(
            company, userName, pin,
        );
      
...
```

and finally:

```
class LoginRepositoryImpl implements LoginRepository {
  //final LoginDatabase _loginDatabase;
  final LoginApiService _loginApiService;
  LoginRepositoryImpl(this._loginApiService);

  @override
  Future<DataState<List<LoginModel>>> getLogonDetails(
     String company, String userName, String pin,
  ) async {
    try {
      final httpResponse = await _loginApiService.getLogonDetails(
        apiKey: telMeApiKey,
        lcomp: company,
        luser: userName,
        lpin: pin,
      );
...
```

as an option for optimization, you can pass through all of the methods not the parameters, but the object containing this parameters:

```
class UserData extends Equitable {
 const UserData({
   required this.companny,
   required this.userName,
   required this.pin,
}
);

 final String company;
 final String userName;
 final String pin;

@override
  List<Object?> get props => [company, userName, pin];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is rather useful. I ended up figuring it out not long before you posted this. I created a LoginDTO with all the params and used that. It's still interesting to see how your solution differs only slightly to what I have though.

Comment: Thanks for the accepted answer. As for different approaches, that’s what I said - in general :)